# Evenly distribute space in multisized title

Tags: css, spacing

I am trying to reproduce old style titles using CSS and HTML. Here is the code I came up with.

```css
body {
  font-family: Palatino;
}

header {
  text-align: center;
}

h1 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: normal;
}

.small {
  font-size: 12pt;
  letter-spacing: .1ch;
}

.medium {
  font-size: 18pt;
  letter-spacing: .2ch;
}

.large {
  font-size: 27pt;
  letter-spacing: .3ch;
}
```

```html
<h1>
  <span class="large">Officia in mollit</span><br>
  <span class="medium">elit anim ut culpa in irure</span><br>
  <span class="small">enim officia excepteur ex ad sint magna</span><br>
  <span class="large">magna ut minimu</span><br>
  <span class="medium">nisi dolore minim aute</span><br>
  <span class="small">nisi dolore minim aute laboris</span><br>
  <span class="medium">ex laboris culpa</span><br>
</h1>
```

However, the problem I have is that the space is not distributed evenly between the different lines of the title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `<br>` elements, and set the span elements to `display: block;` (or replace them with div elements). Set the `line-height: 1` on the `<h1>` element, so the line height will fit the font size.

```css
body {
  font-family: Palatino;
}

header {
  text-align: center;
}

h1 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1;
}

h1 > span {
  display: block;
}

.small {
  font-size: 12pt;
  letter-spacing: .1ch;
}

.medium {
  font-size: 18pt;
  letter-spacing: .2ch;
}

.large {
  font-size: 27pt;
  letter-spacing: .3ch;
}
```

```html
<h1>
  <span class="large">Officia in mollit</span>
  <span class="medium">elit anim ut culpa in irure</span>
  <span class="small">enim officia excepteur ex ad sint magna</span>
  <span class="large">magna ut minimu</span>
  <span class="medium">nisi dolore minim aute</span>
  <span class="small">nisi dolore minim aute laboris</span>
  <span class="medium">ex laboris culpa</span>
</h1>
```